# Measure extension via inner measure

Tags: measure-theory

Is it possible to use "inner measure" in the proof of the [Caratheodory extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem)?

I'm trying to understand why we prefer outer one instead, although definitions of outer and inner measures are dual.

N. B.: I mean $\mu_*(A) = \sup \{\sum \mu(E_i) | E_i\mbox{ disjoint}, E_i \subset A\}$ is the "inner measure," generated by some pre-measure $\mu$, defined on some ring $\mathcal R$. It's not in general use.

So let me explain the problem:

We can proof [superadditivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superadditivity) of $\mu_*$ defined above.

Then we consider $\mathcal M (\mathcal R) = \{A \;|\; \forall E  \in \mathcal R \;\;\mu_*(E\cup A) + \mu_*(E\setminus A) = \mu_*(E)\}.$

Now it's not hard to show that $\mathcal M(\mathcal R)$ closed under finite union and completion.

But I can't prove that $\mathcal M(\mathcal R)$ closed under countable union. Maybe it's not true in general? What is the difference in such symmetrical concepts of inner in outer measure?

Comment: If you drop the disjointness condition, the inner measure is simply the outer measure of the complement. So you will get the same measurable sets.

Comment: But is $E_i$ aren't disjoint, we can duplicate them, so then $\mu_*(A) = \infty$ for every $A$.

Comment: That is true. It also points to a big asymmetry between the approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is very simple counterexample to my construction (with disjoint sets):

Let $\mathcal R$ be the ring of intervals (with and without endpoints) with rational endpoints with usual $\mu$ a.k.a "length" of interval.

Suppose that our construction give us a real good measure $\mu_*$ with some $\mathcal M(\mathcal R)$. Then $\mu_*(X) = 0$ for every countable $X$ and every such $X$ is clearly in $\mathcal M(\mathcal R).$ Also it's not difficult to show that $\mathcal R \subset \mathcal M (\mathcal R)$ and $\mu_*$ really extends $\mu.$

Then we conclude that $\mu_*([0,1]\setminus \mathbb Q) = 1,$ but it's not equal the value of $\mu_*([0,1])\setminus \mathbb Q),$ computed by definition of $\mu_*$ - then it will be 0, because every interval with non-zero length contains a rational point, so only $E \in \mathcal R$ contained in $[0,1]\setminus \mathbb Q$ is $\varnothing.$

Also it is counterexample for such construction of $\mu_*$: $\mu_*(A) =\sup \{\mu(E) | A \supset E \in \mathcal R\},$ which seems to be more dual than mine.